# Copy code example from Zend Site

Tags: zend-framework

How would you copy the code from this example page

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html

(Below the text "Now that we've initialized Zend_Layout and set the Doctype, let's create our site-wide layout:" )

A simple copy paste will also copy the line number or #. Any tricks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate these line numbers as well. The way I do it:

Copy the text to your favorite text editor (notepad won't do, Word for example would) and **block-select** using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> Key.

Let me give you an example with [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org). here I copied text from the said site with all line numbers included. Now I just hold the <kbd>ALT</kbd> button and select normally with my mouse (or using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>arrow keys</kbd>). The result of me selecting only the code sans the line numbers you see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Now I could just copy this code to a new editor.